Duration for a foam insulation box to stay between 2 - 8°C with 8 cooling gel packs 9 each (1.5 kg) are kept inside to maintain the temperature
The size of the box is 620 x 440 x 420 mm (outer dimensions) with a thickness of 35 mm. For how long will the internal temperature remain between 2 - 8 degrees Celsius if the initial temperature after keeping the gel pack is 0 degrees?

Not long if it is in the Sahara, longer if it is in the antarctic...

your specification needs to include outside ambient temperature, and you need to define the heat capacity and size of gel packs.  Also the exact type of "foam" insulation

ambient temperature is 35 degree  and the foam is pe foam gel packs are 1.5 kg each

Where will the box be? Knowing just outside air temperature is not enough, wind can also play a big role.

the box will be placed inside a truck (non refrigerated)

will the time be in hours or minutes and what will be the units for all the other parameters?

Zero hours because as soon as you close the box, the temp will be zero C (below 2 C).

The closest you can get with an analytic calculation of mean box temperature $\overline{T}_{box}$ in time $t$ is this:
$$\overline{T}_{box}(t) = T_{env} + \left(T_{box0}-T_{env}\right)\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{K\cdot A}{m\cdot c_p}\cdot t\right)$$
where:

$T_{env}$ is the environment temperature
$T_{box0}$ is the initial box temperature
$K$ is overall heat transfer coefficient (influenced by box heat conduction properties, but also the environment)
$A$ is the heat transfer area (outside surface area of the box in contact with the environment)
$m\cdot c_p$ is the overall heat capacity of the box

It is quite difficult to calculate some of these terms, so my suggestion would be to run a few test with the box and try to determine the exponentiation constant $k_{exp}$:
$$k_{exp} = \frac{K\cdot A}{m\cdot c_p} = -\frac{1}{t}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\overline{T}_{box}(t)-T_{env}}{T_{box0}-T_{env}}\right)$$
This constant will be different depending on what is in the box and character of the environment, so you may need more constants for different situations.
Finally, to answer your question about the duration the contents of the box will stay under specific temperature $T_{box,max}$, you can calculate this from:
$$t = -\frac{1}{k_{exp}}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{T_{box,max}-T_{env}}{T_{box0}-T_{env}}\right)$$

is k the thermal conductivity of a material

@user49251 k is defined in the answer.

@user49251 $k_{exp}$ as defined in the answer includes conductivity, but also much more. Since it would be very difficult to calculate, I proposed determining it by tests. Conductivity is part of $K$, which also includes heat transfer coefficients on the outside and inside the box. All this along with geometry ($A$) and thermal capacity ($m\cdot c_p$) influences the constant $k_{exp}$.

what is time t  and how to i use this equation to find my problem

Time $t$ is the duration for which the box can stay under specified temperature.

Here’s a rough and ready calculation, but it should get you close.
Assume:
Internal dimensions of box are 0.55x0.37x0.35m and there is no leakage. Then internal area (A) is $1.05m^2$
The thickness (d) is 0.035m
Thermal conductivity of polyethylene foam (k) is $0.05 Wm^{-1}K^{-1}$
The gel pack is 1.5Kg ice at $0^oC$.
The internal temperature of the box is steady at $0^oC$. This means the temperature difference (K) is 35C.
Latent heat of fusion of water (L) is $334\frac{kJ}{kg}$.
Then the formula to calculate heat flow in watts  is $S=\frac{k.A.K}{d}$.
Putting in the numbers we get heat flow is about 52.5W.
The thermal mass of the gelpack is 1.5*L = 501000J.
Time to melt all the ice is $\frac{501000}{45}s$ or about 2hr 39min.
Probably the box will be a little warmer than 0C, there will be a little time to warm up the box to 8C and the air in the box will provide some additional insulation so as a round figure 3hr. (But take this as a maximum time!)
Each extra gel pack will add about another 3hr.
So for 8 gel packs, you should be close to 24hr.
